# Получить title у groupbox в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgroupbox

Я пишу код с использование *PyQt5*. У меня есть форма, в которой есть `groupbox` с названием "Emotion". Как я могу получить текущий `title` этого `groupbox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читать здесь: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgroupbox.html#title-prop

> title : QString
>
> Это свойство содержит текст заголовка группового блока.
> Текст заголовка группового блока будет иметь сочетание клавиш,
> если заголовок содержит амперсанд ('&'), за которым следует буква.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # creates a QGroupBox
        title = '&Emotion'
        qgroupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(title)
        
        print( type(qgroupbox) )
        print( "title -> {}".format(qgroupbox.title() ) )            # <---

        # sets the margins
        left, top, right, bottom = 10, 10, 10, 10
        self.setContentsMargins(left, top, right, bottom)

        # sets the QGroupBox as the central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(qgroupbox)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setWindowTitle('Create a QGroupBox with a title')
    window.resize(400, 400)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за решение! Странно, что pycharm не предложил мне его.